# Adding firewall rule makes multiple entries

Tags: 14.04, networking, firewall, iptables

I am trying to add a rule to my Ubuntu 14 iptables to allow NTP (123) though using the command for **allowing Incoming Traffic on Specific Ports** [Basic iptables How to?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo)

Here is my command:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport ntp -j ACCEPT
```

After I run that I then see and entry in iptables -L liek this:

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ntp
```

So I then use two external sites to do a port scan on that port and both come back and say the port is closed.  So I rebooted, no change.  I then wanted to remove the entry from iptables:

```
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ntp
```

That did not have the desired affect because now I have something like this:
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ntp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ntp
DROP       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ntp
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ntp

I decided to stop there as I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  Is there a command I need to run to actually open the port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, NTP works on UDP. So you can try something like,

```
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 123 --sport 1024:65535 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p udp --sport 123 --dport 1024:65535 -j ACCEPT
```